# Unable to Acess Native code (element) in Xamarin Forms with NETStandard 2.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

My partial class didn't targeting the #if in Xamarin Forms project with NETStandard 2.0

A sample of the problem is:

```
     public partial class App : Application
       {
       #region StaticString
        #if __IOS__
        public static String A
        #endif
        #if __ANDROID__
        public static String A
        #endif
        #if WINDOWS_UWP
        public static String A;         
        #endif
       #endregion

     public App ()
           {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeApplication();

           #region Teste
            #if __IOS__
            A="ios";
            #endif
            #if __ANDROID__
            A="droid";
            #endif
            #if WINDOWS_UWP
            A="UWP;         
            #endif
          #endregion
          }

        }
```

I need to acess and send specific code for my viewmodels but it was unable and invisible for another class (like this String A).

I saw a sample/way in "Accessing Native Views in Code"

Is it only work in Shared Code ?

Regards

Comment: The code you are using for your platform conditions is used in Shared projects use Device.OnPlatform instead

Comment: #if is a COMPILER directive, and the compiler does not know what the runtime platform is

Comment: Like this ?

switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                A="ios";
                break;
           case Device.UWP:
                A="UWP";
                break;
            default:
                A="android"
                break;
        }

Answer (score 2):

The compiler directives are only available in shared code and `Device.OnPlatform` is deprecated. The solution for this is to use `Device.RuntimePlatform` in a switch statement. This would make your code look something like:

```
public static string A;
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
    case Device.iOS:
        A = "ios";
        break;
    case Device.Android:
        A = "droid";
        break;
    case Device.UWP:
        A = "UWP";
        break;
    default:
        A = "unknown";
        break;
}
```

Take a look at the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device) for information on using `Device.RuntimePlatform`